# Detect changes between multiple source files using Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, nunjucks, gulp-4, gulp-nunjucks-render

The original issue I was having  was that the task was running x amount of times for the number of files existing inside `src.pages`, I fixed this by adding the 'changed-in-place' plugin, to compare the last date modified of the source files. This meant that if the modified date hadn't changed, then it didn't run, or if it had changed then it would run, but only the necessary amount of times.

Because the plugin only checks files against the directory passed into the stream, it means it won't check against files inside `src.templates`, which is essentially my .html partial files folder. The workaround I had running was to have a separate task watching for partial files changes, but not run any comparison functionality, this meant that I still had the original problem of the task running multiple times.

**Updated**: Here is a stripped down version of my gulpfile containing everything relevant to my question:

```
var fileFormat = 'html',
    fileExt = '.' + fileFormat;

var src = {
    pages: 'src/pages/**/*' + fileExt,
    templates: 'src/templates/**/*' + fileExt,
};

var dist = {
    pages: './',
    css: './',
};

var config = {
    templates: ['src/templates/', 'src/partials/'],
    pagesWatch: './*' + fileExt, // Directory where pages are output

};

// Browser Sync with code/HTML injection
function bs() {
    browserSync.use(htmlInjector, {
        files: dist.pages + '*' + fileExt
    });
    browserSync.init({
        server: dist.pages,
        files: dist.css + '*.css',
        watchOptions: {
            awaitWriteFinish: {
                stabilityThreshold: 500
            }
        }
    });
}

function nunjucksPages() {
    nunjucksRender.nunjucks.configure([src.templates]);
    return gulp.src([src.pages])
        .pipe(changedInPlace())
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
            path: config.templates,
            ext: fileExt
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist.pages))
}

// Use CommonJS 'exports' module notation to declare tasks
exports.nunjucksPages = nunjucksPages;
exports.bs = bs;

function watch() {
    gulp.watch([src.pages, src.templates], gulp.series(nunjucksPages));
    gulp.watch(config.pagesWatch, gulp.series(htmlInjector));
}

// Runs all the required tasks, launches browser sync, and watches for changes
var build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(nunjucksPages));
var run = gulp.parallel(bs, watch);

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(build, run));
```

**Edit for clarification**: I have a task watching the pages and templates directory for changes, once it does, it runs the `nunjucksPages` function. After the HTML has been compiled by nunjucks, browser sync will detect this and inject the HTML (the 2nd watch task in my code).

The current workaround I have in place is to duplicate both the nunjucks functions, and run them independently - the pages function with the caching (single reload, issue fixed!), and the templates function with no caching (reloading per X amount of pages).

**Related issue and comment**: https://github.com/carlosl/gulp-nunjucks-render/issues/47#issuecomment-240962074

Comment: `watch` should be your answer. E.g.

    gulp.task('src', function() {
      gulp.src(src)
         .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
    });
    gulp.task('watch', function() {
       gulp.start('shell');
       watch(src, function() {gulp.start('src');
    });

Comment: My tasks are being watched correctly. The issue I'm having is with caching. Also, I'm using Gulp v4, hence why my tasks are named functions

Comment: Ahh right.. You may want to rewrite your question to reflect that, as that is how I interpreted it.

Comment: Cheers for pointing out. Feel like I may be missing something entirely, that's preventing me from explaining my issue very well. Been giving me headaches for literally days on end this has..

Comment: Are you sure it's a caching issue and not a compiling issue? Caching doesn't usually occur on html/php files - more-so on css, js.

Comment: In a sense there is no issue. Caching and compiling are working as expected. It's some kind of workaround that I need so that I can perform caching on my templates, but for them to still be detected by nunjucks (which they aren't with caching turned on) and compiled.

Comment: I see a typo - not sure it is in your actual code:  gulp.series('nunjucksPages')  shouldn't be a string.

Comment: Thanks, updated. I never changed it after migrating to v4, but it still worked for some reason.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your github repo?

Comment: Was working from a private server, but it's on here now - https://github.com/lf87/gulp-barebones-boilerplate The code may differ to above slightly, but I've just set it back to its original working state.